# InAppStoreWindow, how to reposition the NSView in NSWindow's title bar when resize?

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, inappstorewindow

I'm using InAppStorewindow (https://github.com/indragiek/INAppStoreWindow) to cuztomize my NSWindows's title bar. What i'm trying to do is to add a logo (image) to my title bar in center position:

```
NSSize logoSize = self.logo.frame.size;
NSRect logoFrame = NSMakeRect(NSMidX(self.window.titleBarView.bounds) - (logoSize.width / 2.f),
                                 NSMidY(self.window.titleBarView.bounds) - (logoSize.height / 2.f),
                                 logoSize.width, logoSize.height);

self.logo.frame = logoFrame;
```

I put the above code in applicationDidFinishedLaunching method.

it works fine, however if I click on the green resize button, the position won't change. So how am I going to call the above code to reposition my logo, when the resize button is clicked and performZoom: is called?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NSWindowDelegate Method

```
- (void)windowDidResize:(NSNotification *)notification
```

By that you will know when the window is resized so you can recalculate the position of your logo.